# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3

Tags: java, jenkins, build

When building project on Jenkins this error is thrown:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs (findbugs) on project module-set-view: Execution findbugs of goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs failed: Java returned: 137

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give it additional memory via MAVEN_OPTS setting

This setting is specified for your plugin requiring at least Xmx384M.

https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/faq.html#How_do_I_avoid_OutOfMemory_errors

> How do I avoid OutOfMemory errors?
>   When running findbugs on a project, the default heap size might not be enough to complete the build. For now there is no way to fork findbugs and run with its own memory requirements, but the following system variable will allow you to do so for Maven:
>   export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx384M
>   You can also use the fork option which will for a new JVM. You then use the maxHeap option to control the heap size

**Configuring MAVEN_OPTS on your computer**

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx384M
```

**Configuring MAVEN_OPTS in Jenkins**

(Just a screen shot, use -Xmx384M for the value, not what is in screenshot)
[image: Jenkins MAVEN_OPTS]
https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=65667926#content/view/65667926

**If further troubleshooting is required**

Jenkins hardware requirements can be found here. If you are running many jobs, then increase your system resources.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/

Jenkins JVM memory can be increased by editing the Jenkins.xml file on the Jenkins server, using the same -Xmx method.

Even though the memory requirements are generally low for Jenkins, having at least a 2GB host memory seems reasonable for a very basic server.

If you go to a production environment, Cloudbees recommendations for heap settings should be followed:

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204859670-Java-Heap-settings-best-practice?mobile_site=true

Comment: If it is a duplicate, then mark the question as such. This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Updated, verified not a duplicate as could be specific to the plugin used.

Comment: Actually, I am using jenkins for the first time and I didnt understand, what you said. Is there a problem with pom file or jenkins?

Comment: what do I have to put in pom.xml?-- MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx384M ??
And I dont have any jenkins.xml file